# Detect Idle in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that will be started(remotly) when it is called. I dont want to keep service running so I want the service be self-stopped when enter in idle time, means few minutes after the last call.
I dont want to stop the service from my remote client because I dont know if I finish to work with, that's why I want to use some Idle event in service side.
There is some way ?
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Add a timer in the Windows Service which is reset on each call. When the timer elapses (some number of minutes later) have it call the service's Stop method, effectively stopping the server once it becomes idle.

**Additional Info**
In order to reduce your coding overhead you're looking for an intercept point to handle this timer. If you're using WCF for your service calls the simplest way to do that is with a custom IParameterInspector added as a service extension. You can add the timer logic into the AfterCall() method so that every service call runs through this same block of code & resets the timer. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S6) for details on implemnting custom behaviors.

If you aren't using WCF it's a little trickier. You could use an AOP framework like Castle Windsor or PostSharp, or design your service in a message passing style. AOP allows you to decorate your methods with a property that will call your reset code. Message passing involves desigining your service's contract such that there is a single generic entry point into the service which inspects the incomping message & routes it to the correct method based on it's contents. As you can imagine, one entry point = one place to add the timer reset code. But neither of these are as clean or easy to implement as the WCF-based solution IMO.

Comment: Yes i was thinking in that, but I was also looking for some other already defined mechanism inside C#. If there is any... ?

Comment: Another question could be then: There is any way to intercept all calls to service in one common place before(or after) execute any method in order to place there this timer and not edit all methods to call a methods to do it ?